# Postgres - Why is it giving the error 'Schema does not exist'

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why am I getting the error 'schema "tp" does not exist'? - I think it is the 'NOT EXISTS' section that is throwing up the error, it doesnt see that I have aliased the table oimport.ead_incident_status AS tp - or I am writing it incorrectly

Any help appreciated

I am trying to run the following:

```
 SELECT
    split_part(inc_number,'INC',2)::integer incident,
    st.status,
    mi_start,
    mi_end

FROM
     odwh_import.ead_incident_status tp
     INNER JOIN odwh_data.ead_incident_status st ON tp.mi_value = st.status_description
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            true
        FROM
            odwh_work.ead_incident_status_audit_s ead
        WHERE
            ead.incident = tp.split_part(inc_number,'INC',2)::integer
        AND ead.status = tp.status
        AND ead.start_datetime = tp.mi_start
        )
AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            true
        FROM
            odwh_work.ead_incident_s
        WHERE
            odwh_data.ead_incident.incident = tp.incident
        AND odwh_data.ead_incident.locked = 't'
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I getting the error 'schema "tp" does not exist'?

Because `tp.split_part(...)` references a function in that schema. You probably meant `split_part(...)`.

Comment: Or maybe `pg_catalog.split_part()` if it's a reference to the built-in function

Comment: thanks for highlighting @sebDieBIn - it was just an error on my part